# Getting error opening Windows. Error 1: Filename must be either an absolute pathname or blocklist

Tags: dual-boot, grub, uefi

I've installed CentOS 6.4 on UEFI machine. Created `/boot/efi` partition and installed grub in it.

But when I open `Other` in the grub menu I get this error:

> Error 1: Filename must be either an absolute pathname or blocklist

I've Windows 8 installed in `/dev/sda2` and here's my `grub.conf` :

```
device (hd0) HD(4,a126000,32000,8531805b-e9fb-4220-bdcd-7eec68f1e1c7)
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,8)/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,8)
        kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=9f88ba7d-4787-4ecb-8294-436170ecd53e rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb$
        initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64.img
title Other
    rootnoverify (hd0,1)
        chainloader +1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use grub in the first place? UEFI already acts as a boot loader and in general it's not required or sensible to chain several boot loaders. If the kernel is compiled with EFI_STUB (most modern kernels are) the UEFI can directly load the kernel.

Comment: @Marco So what should i do when i install CentOS 6.4 ? not to install grub ? But does it give me the option to do that ?

Comment: I don't know about CentOS, but on Debian the grub package is not required. In any case, even if you installed grub, you can use `efibootmgr` to add the kernel to your UEFI boot menu to directly boot the kernel and bypass grub. The only thing to do after a kernel update is to copy the new kernel from `/boot/vmlinuz-version` to `/boot/efi/EFI/foo/vmlinuz-version.efi` and run `efibootmgr` to point to the new version, but that's a simple shell three-liner.

Comment: @Marco Sorry i'm kinda beginner to this, how can i use `efibootmgr` instead of already installed grub ? is efibootmgr is a different bootloader ? because i tried to install it, and i found that it's already installed !

Comment: I wrote a detailed answer here: [What should I do before dual-booting Windows 7 and Debian on EFI?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40775/12779) You can probably skip the kernel compilation part, setting up the efi system partition, copying kernel and initramfs and calling `efibootmgr` should be sufficient on recent distros. `efibootmgr` is not a boot loader, UEFI itself acts as a boot loader and `efibootmgr` is a means to interact with it to to/add/remove/change the operating systems or applications it offers to start during boot.

Comment: @Marco adding kernels via efibootmgr by hand is *boring* and error-prone, I would advise against that.

Rafael, if you were to use my answer for [your previous centos6 efi question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76510/) you wouldn't be that beginner by now. :)

Comment: @MichaelShigorin If it's boring, write a script which does the work for you. If it's error-prone, automate it, so the script executes automatically after every kernel update.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to install [refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) somewhere, I doubt centos6's grub was ever intended to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`chainloader +1` is nonsense in UEFI.  You want an entry like this:

```
menuentry "Windows bootmgfw.efi, generated by Boot-Repair" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 18FE-69D8
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```